# How does Python's super() actually work, in the general case?

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, super, method-resolution-order

There are a lot of great resources on `super()`, including [this](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) great blog post that pops up a lot, as well as many questions on Stack Overflow. However I feel like they all stop short of explaining how it works in the most general case (with arbitrary inheritance graphs), as well as what is going on under the hood.

Consider this basic example of diamond inheritance:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'A foo'

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print 'B foo before'
        super(B, self).foo()
        print 'B foo after'

class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print 'C foo before'
        super(C, self).foo()
        print 'C foo after'

class D(B, C):
    def foo(self):
        print 'D foo before'
        super(D, self).foo()
        print 'D foo after'
```

If you read up on Python's rules for method resolution order from sources like [this](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) or look up the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) for C3 linearization, you will see that the MRO must be `(D, B, C, A, object)`. This is of course confirmed by `D.__mro__`:

```
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

And

```
d = D()
d.foo()
```

prints

```
D foo before
B foo before
C foo before
A foo
C foo after
B foo after
D foo after
```

which matches the MRO. However, consider that above `super(B, self).foo()` in `B` actually calls `C.foo`, whereas in `b = B(); b.foo()` it would simply go straight to `A.foo`. Clearly using `super(B, self).foo()` is not simply a shortcut for `A.foo(self)` as is sometimes taught.

`super()` is then obviously aware of the previous calls before it and the overall MRO the chain is trying to follow. I can see two ways this might be accomplished. The first is to do something like passing the `super` object itself as the `self` argument to the next method in the chain, which would act like the original object but also contain this information. However this also seems like it would break a lot of things (`super(D, d) is d` is false) and by doing a little experimenting I can see this isn't the case.

The other option is to have some sort of global context that stores the MRO and the current position in it. I imagine the algorithm for `super` goes something like:

1. Is there currently a context we are working in? If not, create one which contains a queue. Get the MRO for the class argument, push all elements except for the first into the queue.
2. Pop the next element from the current context's MRO queue, use it as the current class when constructing the `super` instance.
3. When a method is accessed from the `super` instance, look it up in the current class and call it using the same context.

However, this doesn't account for weird things like using a different base class as the first argument to a call to `super`, or even calling a different method on it. I would like to know the general algorithm for this. Also, if this context exists somewhere, can I inspect it? Can I muck with it? Terrible idea of course, but Python typically expects you to be a mature adult even if you're not.

This also introduces a lot of design considerations. If I wrote `B` thinking only of its relation to `A`, then later someone else writes `C` and a third person writes `D`, my `B.foo()` method has to call `super` in a way that is compatible with `C.foo()` even though it didn't exist at the time I wrote it! If I want my class to be easily extensible I will need to account for this, but I am not sure if it is more complicated than simply making sure all versions of `foo` have identical signatures. There is also the question of when to put code before or after the call to `super`, even if it does not make any difference considering `B`'s base classes only.

Comment: "I am not sure if it is more complicated than simply making sure all versions of foo have identical signatures" that is a requirement of using super generally (though you can kinda work around it with kwargs)

Comment: You need to either have identical signatures or use `*args, **kwargs` to mop up anything else that's getting passed around. The first argument to `super` is the class *above which* it should look for the method - in general you want the one immediately above the current one, hence `super(ThisClass, self)`. *"`super(B, self).foo()` is not simply a shortcut for `A.foo(self)`"* - no, it calls the next `foo` implementation in the MRO after `B`, binding it to `self`. Have you looked at the **Related** questions in the sidebar, quite a few seem relevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I have looked at the related questions but as I've said, they really only address simplified versions and not the general case. I have learned recently that `super(B, self).foo()` is not a shortcut for `A.foo(self)` as I've been teaching myself more about it, but it is often actually taught exactly this way. Of course it does not matter in the large majority of cases with single inheritance only, but it does mean in general it is not proper to use `super(cls, self).__init__` with explicit arguments as it makes its way back to `object` eventually.

Comment: It's taught that way because that is what it does in the single-inheritance case, which covers an awful lot of ground. You'll find a lot of learning like that, by necessity we start out on simplifications and in some cases outright lies!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> super() is then obviously aware of the previous calls before it

It's not. When you do `super(B, self).foo`, `super` knows the MRO because that's just `type(self).__mro__`, and it knows that it should start looking for `foo` at the point in the MRO immediately after `B`. A rough pure-Python equivalent would be

```
class super(object):
    def __init__(self, klass, obj):
        self.klass = klass
        self.obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        classes = iter(type(self.obj).__mro__)

        # search the MRO to find self.klass
        for klass in classes:
            if klass is self.klass:
                break

        # start searching for attrname at the next class after self.klass
        for klass in classes:
            if attrname in klass.__dict__:
                attr = klass.__dict__[attrname]
                break
        else:
            raise AttributeError

        # handle methods and other descriptors
        try:
            return attr.__get__(self.obj, type(self.obj))
        except AttributeError:
            return attr
```

> If I wrote B thinking only of its relation to A, then later someone else writes C and a third person writes D, my B.foo() method has to call super in a way that is compatible with C.foo() even though it didn't exist at the time I wrote it!

There's no expectation that you should be able to multiple-inherit from arbitrary classes. Unless `foo` is specifically designed to be overloaded by sibling classes in a multiple-inheritance situation, D should not exist.

Comment: That double loop on the same iterator is very subtle. I think I'd be a bit more explicit and use a single `for` loop with a flag saying if the target class had been found yet (the `return` cases can also be tucked inside the loop): `found_klass = False; for klass in type(self.obj).__mro__: if not found_klass: found_klass = klass is self.klass; elif attrname in klass.__dict__: attr = klass.__dict__[attrname]; try: return attr.__get__(self.obj, type(self.obj)); except AttributeError: return attr; raise AttributeError` (with newlines and indentation in place of the semicolons as necessary).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, this code really helped me understand what is going on. I'm not sure how I missed it, but clearly calling `B.foo` using `super` is not the same as calling `b.foo()` directly because `self` will be an instance of `D` and not `B`, so you can get the entire correct MRO by `type(self.obj).__mro__` instead of `self.klass.__mro__`. Of course no global state is needed, I do not know why I was thinking otherwise. This also explains exactly what happens when the `klass` argument passed is not the owner of the method.

Comment: As for the second part, I agree that it is not expected that you should be able to multiple-inherit from arbitrary classes. However it can be useful in certain circumstances - I have been making some "mixin" classes meant to be multiple-inherited along with SQLAlchemy's declarative base and I am now realizing I may have to go back and make some changes so that things do not come back and bite me in the ass later.

Comment: `super(type[, object-or-type])........The __mro__ attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order used by both getattr() and super().` from python docs. According to the docs, `super` should use `type.__mro__` not `type(object).__mro__`, but which can't solve the question. Or, the docs is wrong ? and where do you come the point " When you do `super(B, self).foo`,`super` knows the MRO because that's just `type(self).__mro__`"

Comment: @MMMMMCCLXXVII: Yeah, according to the docs, it should use the first argument's `__mro__`, but the docs are just wrong there. The first argument's `__mro__` is completely ignored.