# How does `super` know the next class in the MRO?

Tags: python

How does `super` know the next class when searching for an attribute? This questions is vague without code:

From Learning Python 5E book:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self): 
        print('B.__init__')
        super().__init__()

class C:
    def __init__(self): 
        print('C.__init__') 
        super().__init__()

class D(B, C): pass

>>> D()
B.__init__
C.__init__
<__main__.D object at 0x0000000002E927B8>
```

`C.__init__` were called and in my understanding `super` walks all the way through the MRO of class **D** (typically next class after class **D**). So the the first `super` call triggers `B.__init__` in **B** and the second `super` call triggers `C.__init__` in **C**. How does `super` in the other classes resume to the next class in the MRO of **D**?

I found one answer here, but this only explains how `super` works generally:

[How does Python's super() actually work, in the general case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290894/how-does-pythons-super-actually-work-in-the-general-case)

What I'm interested in knowing is how `super` continues in the other classes according to the MRO? I can't see any connection between super objects in the different classes and `super` only receives two arguments `__class__` and the first argument (**self** or **cls**). So how do these super objects get to know the next class in the MRO of class **D**. It's possible that `type(self).__mro__` is the source of the information, but how `super` continues since `iter(type(self).__mro__)` isn't passed along the way to the super objects in other classes? Is this something handled by the compiler? There's has to be state information for `super` somewhere, but I can't see any tangible evidence of that.

Comment: I see you've linked to one of my previous answers on the subject. The code in that answer pretty clearly explains how `super` knows where to start looking. How does that answer not answer your question?

Comment: Also, the first `super().__init__()` call triggers `C.__init__`, not `B.__init__`, and the second one triggers `object.__init__`, not `C.__init__`.

Comment: @user2357112 I read your code and I got the point behind it, I just want to  ask you a question: wouldn't `__getattribute__` be more representative than `__getattr__` in that context? You used `__getattr__` which doesn't work for operator overloading methods (e.g, `__init__`) using your coded `super` class will always return `__init__` from the `super` class itself. Other than that I would say your code pretty much simplified the story, so thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it's not perfectly representative of the built-in `super`. It also doesn't handle the case where the second argument is a class, or where the second argument isn't provided, or the Python 3 0-argument magic, and there are a bunch of other, more esoteric special cases I also didn't handle because I was trying to keep things focused on the MRO-walking logic. The real `super` implementation is 391 lines long; you can see it in [`Objects/typeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l7036).