# Class has no attribute of a variable from a parent class using multiple inheretance

Tags: python, class, attributes, multiple-inheritance, subclassing

This has probably been asked to death, but I really think this question will help someone because I really can't find a question or answer for this.

I have made an effort to boil the code down to its smallest structure (ignoring the dodgy naming)

Firstly here is the stack trace of the issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xx\xx\xx\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    DoSomething().method()
  File "C:\xx\xx\xx\main.py", line 27, in method
    self.some_class_method()
  File "C:\xx\xx\xx\main.py", line 12, in some_class_method
    print(self.variable)
AttributeError: 'DoSomething' object has no attribute 'variable'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the failing code (From top to bottom: lowest level to highest level, to finally calling the highest level class(Highest being the most child)):

```
class ParentConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.variable = 'value'

    def some_class_method(self):
        print(self.variable)


class Config(ParentConfig, SomeClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass


class DoSomething(Config):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass

    def method(self):
        self.some_class_method()


DoSomething().method()
```

I can get the code to work in two ways:

One, remove 'ParentConfig' parent class

```
class Config(<removed>, SomeClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pass
```

Two, call both __init__s separately

```
class Config(ParentConfig, SomeClass):
    def __init__(self):
        ParentConfig().__init__()
        SomeClass().__init__()
        pass
```

Now, to be clear the second 'solution' doesn't work in this example, but it does fix the issue in my program, apologies for not having a perfect example.

The main point is, the class 'DoSomething' can't use self.variable when calling the method using it.

Bonus points if someone can fix my example to work when calling the `ParentConfig().__init__()` and `SomeClass().__init__()` individually but not when using just `super().__init__`

I hope this is enough info. In the mean time I will work on a better example and edit this.

Edit:

TLDR on Karl Knechtels answer for newbies:

Either remove `def __init__(self)` from ParentClass

Or

add a `super().__init__()` to the `def __init__(self)` in ParentClass

Comment: `DoSomething.__mro__` will show you the order in which classes are accessed when calling `super` with a `DoSomething` instances as the root object. `ParentConfig.__init__` needs to call `super().__init__()` so that it behaves when part of a diamond inheritance MRO or you can try swapping the order of `Config` base classes so `SomeClass` comes first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ParentConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

The problem is already here. Anything that has `ParentConfig` as a base, *directly or indirectly*, will stop at this point when following the `super()` chain.

```
class Config(ParentConfig, SomeClass):
```

`Config` (as well as anything that has it as a base, directly or indirectly) will consider `ParentConfig` *before* `SomeClass` when `super()` is called in `Config.__init__`. `SomeClass.__init__` therefore *does not* get called, and the `.variable` is not set.

Python's method for dealing with the "diamond inheritance" problem is that `super()` is *cooperative*. It *does not* route to an immediate base class of the current class. It routes to *the next class in the method resolution order of the actual `self` object*.

Here, it should be used in the `ParentConfig`:

```
class ParentConfig:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

(Or just omit `__init__`, as this is the default behaviour.)

When initializing a `Config` (or a `DoSomething`), this `super()` call will route, not to `object`, but to `SomeClass`, as desired. Why? Because of the MRO, which you can inspect at runtime:

```
>>> Config.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Config'>, <class '__main__.ParentConfig'>, <class '__main__.SomeClass'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> DoSomething.__mro__
(<class '__main__.DoSomething'>, <class '__main__.Config'>, <class '__main__.ParentConfig'>, <class '__main__.SomeClass'>, <class 'object'>)
```

For more details, see [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), the authoritative essay on the topic written by a member of the Python dev team (and also a really good teacher in general).

Comment: Also for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128412/how-does-super-know-the-next-class-in-the-mro

Comment: Also something on the mro from Guido van Rossum: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: That was a damn good answer, thank you for this, apologies for not being able to upvote you. 
I think a TLDR for people newer than I am to classes would be:
super stops looking if the most parent class doesn't call super().__init_() in its def __init__(self):
Also, if your most parent class doesn't have a def __init__(self) then it will also be ok.
My mistake was assuming super().__init__() was only needed if there was a parent class with a def __init__(self)