# What exactly does super() return in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

From Python3's documentation `super()` "returns a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type." What does that mean?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ from SuperClass.")
        print("self object id from SuperClass: " + str(id(self)))

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ from SubClass.")
        print("self object id from SubClass: " + str(id(self)))
        super().__init__()


sc = SubClass()
```

The output I get from this is:

```
__init__ from SubClass.
self object id from SubClass: 140690611849200
__init__ from SuperClass.
self object id from SuperClass: 140690611849200
```

This means that in the line `super().__init__()`, `super()` is returning the current object which is then implicitly passed to the superclass' `__init__()` method. Is this accurate or am I missing something here?

To put it simply, I want to understand the following:

When `super().__init__()` is run,

1. What exactly is being passed to `__init__()` and how? We are calling it on `super()` so whatever this is returning should be getting passed to the `__init__()` method from what I understand about Python so far.
2. Why don't we have to pass in `self` to `super().__init__()`?

Comment: If it returns None, how is the object passed to `__init__`?

Comment: in your example super returns this: `<super: <class 'SubClass'>, <SubClass object>>`.

Comment: `super()` returns `super(WhateverClassYoureDefining, self)`, which is implemented basically like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290894/how-does-pythons-super-actually-work-in-the-general-case/33291315#33291315), but in C.

Comment: You can see the [actual `super` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L7222) on the official Github repo.

Comment: But how is `<super: <class 'SubClass'>, <SubClass object>>` the same object as self?

Comment: What makes you think it's the same object?

Comment: Because they have the same object ids as in my example. Whatever super is returning, isn't it being passed to `__init__`?

Comment: Nope. `super().__init__()` doesn't pass the `super` instance to `__init__`; it passes the `SubClass` instance.

Comment: You aren't getting the IDs of the `super `object.  You are printing the ID of the instance of `Subclass` because you printed `id(self)`

Comment: I know that, but when calling `super().__init__()`, `__init__()` is being called on whatever is returned by `super()` right? That must mean that `super()` is returning the instance `sc`.

Comment: You're using an overly simplistic mental model of how Python methods and attributes work. `super().__init__()` means "look up the `__init__` attribute of whatever `super()` returns, and whatever object that attribute lookup returns, *which could be anything*, call it". `super` implements attribute lookup differently from most types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> returns a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
> sibling class of type.

This `proxy` is an object that acts as the method-calling portion of the parent class.  It is not the class itself; rather, it's just enough information so that you can use it to call the parent class methods.

If you call `__init__()`, you get your own, local, sub-class `__init__` function.  When you call `super()`, you get that proxy object, which will redirect you to the parent-class methods.  Thus, when you call `super().__init__()`, that proxy redirects the call to the parent-class `__init__` method.

Similarly, if you were to call `super().foo`, you would get the `foo` method from the parent class -- again, re-routed by that proxy.

Is that clear to you?

#### Responses to OP comments

> But that must mean that this proxy object is being passed to
> `__init__()` when running `super().__init__()` right?

Wrong. The proxy object is like a package name, such as calling `math.sqrt()`. You're not passing `math` to `sqrt`, you're using it to denote which `sqrt` you're using. If you wanted to pass the proxy to `__init__`, the call would be `__init__(super())`. That call would be semantically ridiculous, of course.

> When we have to actually pass in self which is the sc object in my example.

No, you are *not* passing in `sc`; that is the *result* of the object creation call (internal method `__new__`), which includes an invocation of `init`.  For `__init__`, the `self` object is a new item created for you by the Python run-time system.  For most class methods, that first argument (called `self` out of convention, `this` in other languages) is the object that invoked the method.

Comment: But that must mean that this proxy object is being passed to `__init__()` when running `super().__init__()` right?

Comment: When we have to actually pass in self which is the `sc` object in my example.

Comment: So for clarification, when running `super().__init__()`, `self` is passed to `__init__()` implicitly here?

Comment: Good; that's close enough for a useful understanding.  The system supplies an empty object and updates it according to your commands in your `__init__` method.  You can't pass in the object, because it doesn't exist yet -- that's what `__init__` is doing for you.

Comment: @PM2Ring; thanks for the catch.  I wrote too fast with a low blood sugar.  :-)

Comment: @Prune Does the proxy object you mentioned here is the same object as `sc` and that object has reduced its method access to its parent class's methods. Am I right?

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara: not quite.  `sc` is a main program variable which will refer to the object upon return from `__init__`, after the proxy is fully instantiated and initialized.  The proxy does have more method access than only those of its parent class ... but SO comments are not the place to discuss such details.

Comment: @Prune Thank you, I will ask such a question after 6 months. I have to wait because of this question ban. I totally get it. I will  ask it definitely

Answer (score 6):

> This means that in the line `super().__init__()`, `super()` is returning the current object which is then implicitly passed to the superclass' `__init__()` method. Is this accurate or am I missing something here?

```
>>> help(super)  
super() -> same as super(__class__, <first argument>)
```

`super` call returns a proxy/wrapper object which remembers:

- The instance invoking `super()`
- The class of the calling object
- The class that's invoking `super()`

This is perfectly sound. `super` always fetches the attribute of the *next* class in the hierarchy ( really the MRO) that has the attribute that you're looking for. So it's not returning the current object, but rather and more accurately, it returns an object that remembers enough information to search for attributes higher in the class hierarchy.

---

> 1. What exactly is being passed to `__init__()` and how? We are calling it on `super()` so whatever this is returning should be getting passed to the `__init__()` method from what I understand about Python so far.

You're almost right. But `super` loves to play tricks on us. `super` class defines `__getattribute__`, this method is responsible for attribute search. When you do something like: `super().y()`, `super.__getattribute__` gets called searching for `y`. Once it finds `y` it passes the instance that's invoking the `super` call to `y`. Also, `super` has `__get__` method, which makes it a descriptor, I'll omit the details of descriptors here, refer to the documentation to know more. This answers your second question as well, as to why `self` isn't passed explicitly.

*Note: `super` is a little bit different and relies on some magic. Almost for all other classes, the behavior is the same. That is:

```
a = A()  # A is a class 
a.y()    # same as A.y(a), self is a
```

But `super` is different:

```
class A:
    def y(self):
        return self
class B(A):
    def y(self)
        return super().y()   # equivalent to: A.y(self)
b = B()
b.y() is b  # True: returns b not super(), self is b not super()
```

Comment: It seems like it only remembers two things—not three

Comment: When `super` is invoked in instance methods, there would be three things in the proxy object: `__thisclass__`, `__self_class__`, `__self__` all of which are set according to the place where the `super` call takes place.

Comment: @NeilG  Yes, right. `__thisclass__` to choose the next class in the MRO. You're technically right, but depending on the internal implementation of `super` which I'm not aware of outside Python code.

Comment: @NeilG `__self__` could be `None` now I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple test to investigate what CPython does for `super`:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        return super()

    @classmethod
    def g(cls):
        return super()

    def h(selfish):
        selfish = B()
        return super()

class C(B):
    pass

c = C()
for method in 'fgh':
    super_object = getattr(c, method)()
    print(super_object, super_object.__self__, super_object.__self_class__, super_object.__thisclass__)  # (These methods were found using dir.)
```

The zero-argument `super` call returns an object that stores three things:

- `__self__` stores the object whose name matches the first parameter of the method—even if that name has been reassigned.
- `__self_class__` stores its type, or itself in the case of a class method.
- `__thisclass__` stores the class in which the method is defined.

(It is unfortunate that `__thisclass__` was implemented this way rather than fetching an attribute on the method because it makes it impossible to use the zero-argument form of `super` with meta-programming.)

The object returned by `super` implements `getattribute`, which forwards method calls to the type found in the `__mro__` of `__self_class__` one step after `__thisclass__`.

Comment: (This answer is based on @direprobs 's answer.)