# Python AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'testnet', however the attribute appears when __dict__ is called on super?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager

class Binance_Data(Client):
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret, requests_params=None, tld='us'):
        super().__init__(api_key, api_secret, requests_params=None, tld='us')

    def data_stream_test(self, data):
        print('------------------')
        print(f"Event Title: {data['e']}")
        print(f"Closing Price: {data['c']}")
        print(convert_unix_to_utc(data['E']))
        print('------------------')

    def data_stream(self):
        ds = BinanceSocketManager(super())
        conn_key = ds.start_symbol_ticker_socket('XLMUSDT', data_stream_test)
        ds.start()
```

I have this class that inherits the binance client to read data from its API. I then call the BinanceSocketManager which takes in an instance of the binance Client. However, when I run the program I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'testnet'
```

But when I print `super().__dict__` in a test method to get the attributes it shows testnet as an attribute of super:

```
{...,'testnet': False, 'timestamp_offset': -8}
```

I have no problem calling parent methods such as `super().get_ticker()`, however I get an error here.

Comment: Why are you using `super()` there, rather than just `self`?  An instance of your class *is* an instance of `Client`, as well.

Comment: @jasonharper yes you are right, thank you!

Comment: @jasonharper make an answer so i can mark it as answered and vote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` does not return the class itself but a proxy to call the superclass methods, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725483/what-exactly-does-super-return-in-python-3).

Instead of `super()` try `self`.